# devise custom user attribute acessors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to customize the authetication.

I've done a custom confirmation mail view `app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb` as follows:

```erb
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>
<p>
  Thanks for registering. You have registered through <%= @resource.provider %>.
  The account data has been created automatically as follows:
</p>
<ul>
  <li><strong>User Name:</strong> <%= @resource.name %></li>
  <li><strong>Password:</strong> <%= @resource.password %></li>
</ul> 
<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

The `@resource.provider` returns a string such as `'facebook'`, `'twitter'`, `'github'`.

If I wanted to customize these strings, let's say print instead `'Facebook'`, `'Twitter'`, `'GitHub'`…, how should I do it? My first idea is a method

```
def print_cool_provider(provider)
  if provider == 'facebook'
    return 'Facebook'
  else if ...
    ...
  end
end
```

I consider a finite short list of possible providers that I can handle one by one. My real questions go more with MVC, Rails and Devise:

Where should I define this method to respect the MVC pattern and at the same time be able to call it from the `confirmation_instructions.html.erb` template?

Comment: If you only want to print a human readable (first letter upper case) string, you can use this in your confirmation instructions: ```<%= @resource.provider.humanize %>``` You can take a look here for more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-humanize

Comment: this was my first thought, but i wondered if there is some better option that respects more the MVC pattern, just in case i wanted to expand it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a simple helper, like so:

```
# app/helpers/provider_helper.rb
module ProviderHelper

  # only special cases, where #titlecase won't suffice
  PROVIDER_NAMES = {
    'github'        => 'GitHub',
    'google_oauth2' => 'Google'
  }

  def provider_name(user)
    PROVIDER_NAMES[user.provider] || user.provider.titlecase
  end
end
```

A **better approach** would be [a presenter](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/09/26/presenting-the-rails-presenter-pattern/) (or decorator), though.

- [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) would be my first choice
- the Ruby Toolbox list [a lot of alternatives](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_presenters)

---

*N.B.: I would not submit the password via email, unless it is encrypted.*

Comment: When signing up through a provider with OAuth, a random password is generated by Devise. My idea is to send this password to users through email, and this way they are not forced to always log in through a provider.
However I'm new and I, of course accept suggestions, as my ideas might not be always right.
Do you mean I should encrypt the whole email? Or maybe it would be enough to only send the password when it is one that has been generated by devise. Thanks a lot anyway, I'll probably use presenters.

Comment: I'd suggest to not send passwords *at all*. If you encrypt the mail, you either require the receiver to use PGP (not a bad thing, though) or to transmit the decryption key, somehow, preferably also not unencrypted... On the other hand, *the whole purpose* of OAuth providers is, that you don't have to manage n password, but only one for the provider, through which your users will identify themselves. If You insist on a local password, make it optional and let the user choose their own after the first login.

Comment: Okey, I see your point, I'll probably not use local passwords then.
Anyway, presenters fill a lack that involves other parts of the web application, so Draper will be really helpful for me. Thanks again!